# S3 upload sending events is working locally with deferred.notify() but not on server

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3

I am sending an object to s3 to upload and locally I get back an 'httpUploadProgress' event. This notifies a .progress call on the function and then updates a record with its progress. It works fine locally but not on the server. Any ideas would be appreciated. I've included two snippets of code. I'm using google servers, not sure if it's an issue with the code or the server settings :/

```js
s3.uploadVideo = function (filepath, videoName, publisher_id) {
 var deferred = q.defer();
 var body = fs.createReadStream(filepath);
 var s3obj = new AWS.S3({
  params: {
   Bucket: transcodeConfig.NonTranscodedVideoBucket,
   Key: publisher_id + '/' + videoName
  }
 });
 s3obj.upload({Body: body}).
  on('httpUploadProgress', function (evt) {
   deferred.notify(evt);
   return
  }).
  send(function (err, data) {
   if (!err) {
    deferred.resolve(data);
    return
   } else {
    deferred.reject(err);
    return
   }
  });
 //deferred.resolve({})
 return deferred.promise;
}
```

```js
aws_api.s3.uploadVideo(file.path, fileName, publisher_id ).progress(function(progress){
  return models.videos.findOneAndUpdate({_id : trackingId},{uploadProgress: progress, file_type:fileExtension},function(err,data){
   if(err){
    return next(err);
   }else{

    return data;
   }
  })
 })
```

Comment: Is it uploading properly though? You mentioned Google Servers with S3. Have you checked if your CORS settings are working properly? I ran into similar problem due to that.